# QGIS 3.18 and 3.16 LTR install. GRASS and SAGA not working. MacOS OSX

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, saga, macos

I have tried to update QGIS on Mac to either version 3.18 or 3.16 using the installers on the QGIS page (https://qgis.org/en/site/). I have been having issues getting the GRASS and SAGA providers running.

Error message below.

GRASS init error: Problem in GRASS initialization, GRASS provider and plugin will not work : Module built against version 2021-02-10T17:13:06+00:00 but trying to use version 2021-02-10T17:08:53+00:00. You need to rebuild GRASS GIS or untangle multiple installations.

No idea how to rebuild GRASS or untangle installations

Big sur 11.2

Comment: The message means that the software components have not been packaged at the same time. Please re-do the installation.

Comment: But its the installer that has the packages that don't match ? so I need a new installer?

Comment: I think that the producer of the installer needs to rebuild it (not sure where you got the installer, please edit above and add an URL)